# flask-appbuilder table view of all columns in table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-appbuilder

Using Flask-Appbuilder I can't work out how to do the seemingly simple task of displaying all values from all columns in a table as a ModelView ie:

```
col1    col2    col3
1       x       y
2       p       z
```

etc..

The canonical example on the flask-apbuilder uses hard coded column names:

```
class ContactModelView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Contact)

    label_columns = {'contact_group':'Contacts Group'}
    list_columns = ['name','personal_celphone','birthday','contact_group']

    show_fieldsets = [
        ('Summary',{'fields':['name','address','contact_group']}),
        ('Personal Info',{'fields':['birthday','personal_phone','personal_celphone'],'expanded':False}),
    ]
```

While a could just do a PRAGMA table_info(table_name) and feed the result back in to list_columns, I was hoping there may be an alternate way to doing this?

Comment: having the same problems. very surprised at how something so simple doesn't seem to be possible to implement?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to just use JQuery DataTables with Ajax to get around this. There is a good tutorial for simple table display here:

https://sarahleejane.github.io/learning/python/2015/08/09/simple-tables-in-webapps-using-flask-and-pandas-with-python.html